# How to display all records that were in rowcount that had a rowcount of 1 or more?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get all the rows that were counted in the query that have a count more than 1. I am able to return this data from this query:

```
SELECT Claims.PT_SSN, Claims.FROM_DATE, Count(Claims.FROM_DATE) AS [COUNT], Claims.PROC_CODE, Claims.CHARGE_AMT, Claims.UNITS, Count(Claims.FROM_DATE) AS COUNT_DATES INTO mue_errors
FROM Claims INNER JOIN mue_values ON Claims.PROC_CODE = mue_values.cpt_code
WHERE (((Claims.PROC_CODE)=[mue_values].[cpt_code]))
GROUP BY Claims.PT_SSN, Claims.FROM_DATE, Claims.PROC_CODE, Claims.CHARGE_AMT, Claims.UNITS, Claims.INEL_AMT_1
HAVING (((Claims.CHARGE_AMT)<>[INEL_AMT_1]) AND ((Count(Claims.FROM_DATE))>1));


PT_SSN      FROM_DATE COUNT PROC_CODE  CHARGE_AMT UNITS COUNT_DATES
406588032   1/17/2014   2   80053      $62.58       1     2
406588032   1/17/2014   2   80061      $144.93      1     2
406588032   1/17/2014   2   83036      $71.39       1     2
```

This is the right number of rows in the table but I want to get each of the two lines that were counted for each `Proc_Code`.

So results should be:

```
PT_SSN      FROM_DATE    PROC_CODE CHARGE_AMT    UNITS  
406588032   1/17/2014       80053    $62.58        1   
406588032   1/17/2014       80053    $62.58        1   
406588032   1/17/2014       80061    $144.93       1    
406588032   1/17/2014       80061    $144.93       1   
406588032   1/17/2014       83036    $71.39        1   
406588032   1/17/2014       83036    $71.39        1
```

Comment: There is a query wizard for this.

Comment: why units go from `1` to `11`? so you just want puplicate the lines?

Comment: yes sorry units should be 1 I have edited post, yes I want to duplicate the lines but remove the row_count, I have tried query wizard does not give me desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want duplicate lines you can use `union all` and that will keep duplicated

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table1
```

Comment: This is closer but it says I have too many fields And I need all the fields shown in the row

Comment: can you try this on a smaller sample table? not sure if you have a syntaxis problem or your query explote access.

Comment: I was able to get this to somewhat work, I got just the fields and the ids of the duplicates that I wanted then created them into a temp table and compared that temp tables id to the main claim table to create another table with all the values of the same code billed on the same day...just thought there would be an easier way.